# Javascript: make the focus on the div parent onClick input

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an input field and a span inside a div parent. What i want to accomplish is to make the focus on the div on focusing on the input. The problem is that when i click on the span the div get focused which is not the case for the input. 
how to make the input lose its focus and then make the focus on the div onClick on the input ?

Here's my code:

```css
.img {
  background: #ef1111;
}
```

```html
<div tabindex='0'>
<input type='text'/>
<span class='img'>Try me !</span>
</div>
```

Comment: do you use jQuery ?

Comment: Please update your question to include your JavaScript.

Comment: @SurenSrapyan no i had to work only with javascript and react in my project.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want to do, if not please explain a little more :

```
div{
    pointer-events: none;
}

 [...]
<div tabindex='0'> 
<input type='text' autofocus/>
<span class='img'>Try me !</span>
</div>
```

Comment: No, in fact, i need to make a focus on the div when i click on its children. when i click on the span the div become focused but this is not the case for the input